# 3 part structure iPad application

Tags: ios, ipad

I want to make an iPad application with upper and lower part. Buttons will be positioned at the lower part and when clicked on, only the mid part will change. What kind of structure do I have to use? I don't have problems with standart windows, tabs and buttons, but I don't know how to make sure that the mid part doesn't change.

Comment: You can divide your screen into 3 UIViews, top - mid and bottom and put the buttons into proper UIView. When you click on a button, you can change only a partial of view by moving these UIViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 3 UIViews in to the screen , 1st screen upper level, 2nd screen mid level, 3rd screen lower level screen in and its gives you result which you want.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnSubmit;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblClick;
- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController
int i=1;
@synthesize view1;
@synthesize view2;
@synthesize view3;
@synthesize btnSubmit;
@synthesize lblClick;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
        [self setView1:nil];
        [self setView2:nil];
        [self setView3:nil];
        [self setBtnSubmit:nil];
        [self setLblClick:nil];
        [super viewDidUnload];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    }

    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    }

    - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        // Return YES for supported orientations
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    }

    - (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender 
    {

        btnSubmit.tag = i++;
        lblClick.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        if(i%2 == 0)
        {
            view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
        else
        {
            view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
    }
    @end
```

Above example is just an idea to work with 3 views in 1 viewcontroller, in this example take 3 views where 1st view just blank , 2 view have label which display the value of click on button which is in view3. and on the click on button is label value is even then view2 backround color is changed ti blue color is the vaqlue is odd then it became green.
in view 3 have jus button.

Comment: could you make an example for this? i want to learn how can i use uiview class to do this, thank you